# Not able to find Files with PathMatcher

Tags: java, java-8, nio

am trying something following==>

```
String glob = "glob:/Users/CSDSD/Desktop/bahar/bamboo/v1/latest/git/openssl/openssl" + startingDir+File.separatorChar+"**/ms/*.c";
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(glob);
boolean isMatches  = matcher.matches(Paths.get("/Users/CSDSD/Desktop/bahar/bamboo/v1/latest/git/openssl/openssl/ms/applink.c"));
assertTrue(isMatches);
```

fails. what am doing wrong here ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if `startingDir` is an empty string, and you are running on a non-Windows platform, you are globbing like this:

```
glob:  /Users/CSDSD/Desktop/bahar/bamboo/v1/latest/git/openssl/openssl/**/ms/*.c
path:  /Users/CSDSD/Desktop/bahar/bamboo/v1/latest/git/openssl/openssl/ms/applink.c
```

> The `**` characters matches zero or more characters crossing directory boundaries.

But even at zero characters, there are 2 `/` characters in the glob, so it cannot match against a single `/` character in the path.